# Synonymise [smartdevice] with [smart-device]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[smartdevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartdevice) and [smart-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-device) are obviously synonyms but I can't do it myself. Or perhaps I should just go ahead and retag one of those?

Comment: Are those tags useful for categorization of questions in any way?

Comment: @RobertHarvey not sure I just noticed that by accident but it seems so http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228293(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I would say keep `smart-device` and burinate/retag `smartdevice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done! (just to mark as accepted)